# ExternalEvaluate Python print is printing an extra empty cell with newline

Tags: external-calls, python

When using print command in `ExternalEvaluate["Python","print(1+1)"]` or `ExternalLanguage` cell using >, there is always an extra cell generated after the print. This is particularly annoying when debugging code where print is inside a loop. Am i the only one facing this problem or others also see this? Help.

I am using version WL-11.3 and Python-3.

As an example consider the following python function.

```
def solution(N):
    max_gap=0
    current_gap=0

    while N>0 and N%2==0:
        print([N,current_gap,max_gap,"{0:b}".format(N)])
        N//=2

    while N>0:
        if N%2==0:
            current_gap+=1
        else:
            if current_gap!=0:
                max_gap=max(current_gap,max_gap)
                current_gap=0

        print([N,current_gap,max_gap,"{0:b}".format(N)])
        N//=2

    return max_gap
```

try calling the following as follows:

```
solution(1042)
```

Comment: Does it help that `ExternalEvaluate["Python", "1+1"]` returns its value without the need of the Python `print` function.

Comment: No because in a large function when debugging the only way to get intermediate results is by printing them out before the final return in a function.

Comment: It would help if you were to provide a minimal example of the Python looping function with the `print`.

Comment: @Edmund I have added an example for python function where loops are involved.

Comment: Does `print(1+1,end='')` helps?